# How do i fix this pywin32 CompatableDC error?

Tags: python, memory, pywin32

Ok, so I get this error (error: CreateCompatibleDC failed) when I use this function:

```
import win32api, win32ui, win32gui, win32con
def grab():
    global hwin, width, height, left, top
    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
    srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
    memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
    memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
    memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    #bmp.SaveBitmapFile(memdc, 'screenshot.bmp')
    return BMP(bmp, memdc)
hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
```

It says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 1, in <module>
    grab()
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 9, in grab
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
error: CreateCompatibleDC failed
```

I figure this is because I have too many DCs, but when I delete the DCs, it doesn't fix anything. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What are width and height when it fails?

Comment: I assume they would be the same, but they aren't even used in the part where it fails so it seams irrelevant to me.

Comment: Catch the exception and `print win32api.FormatMessage()` to find out why it is failing.